# Ruby 3.0 isn't compatible with lower version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now I am studying Ruby on Rails in Ruby 1.9.3 environment.

But I saw many articles that ruby 1.x sources doesn't work in ruby 2.0 and 3.0.

If so, is it mean that I have to study again Ruby 2.0 or 3.0 when Ruby on Rails has been updated to run under Ruby 2.0 or 3.0?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing Ruby on Rails with Ruby. There is no Ruby 3.0, but there is a Ruby on Rails 3.0.

The current versions of Ruby are: 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 which was just released.

The current versions of Rails are: 2.3.14, 3.0.10, and 3.1.1.

Ruby 2.0 hasn't seen a release yet and remains a theoretical construct at this point.

Comment: Theoretical yes, but work has officially started: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2819001. Also 1.9.2 should soon disappear from this list, 1.9.3 is the way to go for 1.9. Technically 1.8.6 is still around too btw, but this version proliferation should stop soon I hope.

Comment: All versions of Ruby are technically still around, but I don't think anyone's expected to support anything less than 1.8.7. What I mean by theoretical is nobody knows what Ruby 2.0 will be because it's not done yet.

Comment: By technically still around I meant there are in fact people running productive apps on it. :-(

Comment: People are running productive apps on IE6 just the same, but I prefer to pretend they don't exist. Ignorance is bliss, no?

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/version.h has `#define RUBY_VERSION "2.0.0"`. I wouldn't say "theoretical construct" so much as "work in progress" - there are features in trunk that aren't in 1.9.3.

Comment: This was a good answer, but obsolete now: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/

Comment: In ten years when Ruby 3.0 comes out, this answer will be even more obsolete. We're at Ruby 2.0 and Ruby on Rails 4.0 now. And so it goes.

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) is to [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org) as [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is to [Jquery](http://jquery.com/).

One is a language, and the other is really just a bunch of files (scripts, like in a play) that handle a lot of background jobs and tasks that you might need done when building a Ruby application. Rails is more commonly referred to as a *framework*, it's really just a pattern or paradigm for helping you structure your code.

To make more sense of this, you could try using an alternate framework to Rails, like [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/), which is written in Ruby too, but is not Rails. It's Padrino. Same idea, ostensibly.

I recommend reading a very simple vanilla book on Ruby, which goes nowhere near any of the frameworks, like [this one](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/) by Zed Shaw (which was not originally written for Ruby and so doesn't really go into the more complex and exciting stuff for which Ruby is known, like [metaprogramming](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/)) but which will give you a broad based insight into how it works.

Then, in a month or so, move on to [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). Good luck.

Comment: Why use a book that doesn't get into what the language is good for (and was written by someone who bashes the language now...)? How about http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ instead?

Comment: Ha, fair point. Although his book doesn't go into metaprogramming, it's full of exercises that get you where you need to be to start on the harder stuff. I see the one you linked to was written for Ruby 1.6. I will give it a whilr, why not.

Comment: That's the version still available for free. There is a paper version for 1.9 available for sale.